# Needing an opinion about a code

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, logcat

I know that I already asked about NullPointerException, but I found another mistake in my code, and can't find and alternative to solve it. Thanks in advance. Here follows the codes:

```
03-07 14:11:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(897): Process: br.com.agendadecontatos, PID: 897
03-07 14:11:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(897): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 14:11:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(897): at br.com.agendadecontatos.ProvedorDeContatos.toString(ProvedorDeContatos.java:50)
```

Let me make it more clear, because some people are saying that my question is unuseful or something like that. I'm new in Java programming, and really don't know how to solve this problem. I hope that there is someone in StackOverflow that will understand my situation. I'm only asking for help. Say whats is missing before downvoting. Thanks.

```
 @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
          return Nome + "-"  + Telefones.get(0);   // <- the error is here
          //the error is here
    }
```

Here is the whole code:

```
package br.com.agendadecontatos;

import java.util.List;
public class ProvedorDeContatos
{
      private String ID;
      private String Nome;
      private String Sobrenome;
      private List<ProvedorDeContatos> Telefones;     

      public String getID()
      {
          return ID;
    }
    public void setID(String string)
    {
          ID = string;
    }
    public String getNome() 
    {
          return Nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) 
    {
          Nome = nome;
    }     
    public List<ProvedorDeContatos> getTelefones() 
    {
          return Telefones;
    }
    public void setTelefones(List<ProvedorDeContatos> telefones) 
    {
          Telefones = telefones;
    }
    public String getSobrenome() 
    {
          return Sobrenome;
    }
    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) 
    {
          Sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }    

    //Metodo sobreescrito para que não aparece o nome do componente na listView

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
          return Nome + "-"  + Telefones.get(0);
    }

    //função criada após o erro com o setTelefones na classe Telefone

    public void setTelefones(String telefones)
    {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 
}
```

Comment: Do System.out.println(Nome); System.out.println(Telefones) and tell me what you see in the console.

Comment: Still appears the message that "Unfortunately, the application has stopped."

Comment: It seems apparent that either Nome or Telefones is null.  Did you ever create them??  (Remember, declaring is not the same as allocating/creating.  A declared object reference is initialized to null by default.)

Comment: Yea, I did. Look at the 9th line "private List<ProvedorDeContatos> Telefones;". I changed "return Nome + "-"  + Telefones.get(0);" to "return "Nome - "+this.Nome+",Telefones - "+this.Telefones;", and the application started running! This made me think that shouldn't be a problem in variable declaration. The problem may be on the sequence of the code in this line.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `Telefones` variable is null at the point where you call `get` on it.  That's why the attempt to call `get` fails and throws the exception.

A `NullPointerException` typically means that something tried to call a method or access a field on a variable that's null.  Once you find the line where it's happening, look carefully at the variables that are being used on that line.  In this case, there are two:  `Nome` and `Telefones`.

`Nome` is okay because it's just being joined to another string with `+`, and that kind of string joining doesn't throw `NullPointerException`.  (t just puts the word "null" into the string instead.)  So even if `Nome` were null, it wouldn't cause an exception.

That leaves the `Telefones.get(0)` call.  Trying to call a method on a null object always causes a `NullPointerException`, and there's nothing else on that line that could cause one, so it must be this.